# Работа с GridView

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Работаю с `GridView` впервые, почему-то не срабатывает слушатель нажатий, хотя со стороны вроде код правильный. Подскажите пожалуйста, где кроется ошибка?

**activity**

```
public class SelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageButton button1, button2, button3;
    ImageButton[] buttons = {button1, button2, button3};
    GridView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this, buttons));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**adapter**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ImageButton[] b;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, ImageButton[] b) {
        mContext = c;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return b.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return b[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    // public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ImageView imageView;
    // if (convertView == null) {
    // // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    // imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    // imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    // } else {
    // imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    // }
    //
    // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    // return imageView;
    // }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View grid;

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, parent, false);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textpart);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_add_money_t);
        textView.setText("Картинка " + String.valueOf(position));

        return grid;
    }
}
```

**activity_select.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Добавьте ещё ваш файл макета, пожалуйста, -  activity_select.xml

Comment: @Ksenia, обновил пост.

Comment: а метод getView у вас вызывается?

Comment: @Ksenia, `getView()`, если не ошибаюсь, вызывается в `setAdapter()`, да и дело не в нем, таблица отрисовывается нормально. В данном вопросе слушатель не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код выглядит правдоподобно, все что приходит в голову - так это создать свой листенер.

Я добавил в ваш код адаптера пару строк:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ImageButton[] b;


    public interface Callback{
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    public void setListener(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public GridAdapter(Context c, ImageButton[] b) {
        mContext = c;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return b.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return b[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    // public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ImageView imageView;
    // if (convertView == null) {
    // // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    // imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    // imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    // } else {
    // imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    // }
    //
    // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    // return imageView;
    // }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View grid;

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, parent, false);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textpart);
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_add_money_t);
        textView.setText("Картинка " + String.valueOf(position));

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (callback != null) {
                            callback.onClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                });
        return grid;
    }
}
```

и добавить классе где вы создаете GridView:

```
GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, buttons);
adapter.setListener(new GridAdapter.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(int position){
        //do something
    }
});
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Сделал как Вы указали. Такая же тишина... в `onClick()` ничего не срабатывает. Чудеса какие-то. Гуглил, везде в примерах простой метод  `setOnItemClickListener()` как в первом посте, а тут почему-то не работает.

Comment: Если не работают два очевидных варианта - значит где то есть хитрая ошибка))) Возможно в тосте, попробуйте вместо тоста выводить просто строку в логи

Comment: Использовал совет из [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191914/how-to-add-gridview-setonitemclicklistener) примера и поместил слушатель на кнопку в самом адаптере `imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...`, тогда клик отрабатывается нормально. Но так весьма неудобно, чтоб достучаться до элементов активити...

Comment: ааа, даа, я ошибочку допустил, надо было вешать не на корневой элемент, а на какую то вьюху! Так а чем вас подобные способы не устраивают, они по сути ни чем не отличаются от стандартного, ведь так вы можете создавать разные листенеры для разных событий.

Comment: Я подправил ответ, повесил листенер на imageButton попробуйте протестить

Comment: Так работает. Правда не совсем понятен принцип работы этой заморочки с интерфейсом. Да и приходится получается изобретать велосипед, жаль стандартный не работает.

Comment: стандартный тоже по-идеии должен работать, я думаю просто где то что то упустили

Comment: Может наследоваться надо не от `BaseAdapter`, видел примеры кто-то юзал `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: c BaseAdapter долно рабоать , попробуйте повторить пример из документации https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: С примера все отлично работает. В примере в качестве единицы сетки используется `ImageView`, у меня же два элемента `ImageButton` + `TextView` через разметку `grid.xml`. Так вот, посовмещав код, заметил, что стандартный `listener` перестает работать, когда в качестве элемента сетки используется не конкретная вьюшка, а простая `View` с несколькими элементами через разметку.

Comment: Хм.. интересно почему так. Ну в таком случае можете делать так как в моем ответе, может есть другие способы но я только этот знаю

Comment: Так и сделал. В любом случае спасибо за помощь) Не могли бы в кратце описать для чего `callback`?

Comment: Вот обнаружил еще момент интересный. Сделал `grid` с одним элементом, но опять `listener` не работает! Методом тыка установил, что он нормально работает с `ImageView` (как в доках), но не работает с `ImageButton` и `Button`, даже если это просто один элемент таблицы.